# On the distances from an algebraic curve to integer points

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be an algebraic plane curve, considered as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. For each $\vec x \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus (C \cap \mathbb{Z}^2)$ define

$$\displaystyle D(\vec x) = \inf_{\vec y \in C} \lVert \vec x - \vec y \rVert_2.$$

Define the *boundary exponent* of $C$, say $\theta = \theta(C)$, by the property that there for all $\varepsilon > 0$ all but finitely many $\vec x \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus (C \cap \mathbb{Z}^2)$ satisfy

$$\displaystyle D(\vec x) \geq \lVert \vec x \rVert_2^{- \theta - \varepsilon}$$

and there are infinitely many $\vec x \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus (C \cap \mathbb{Z}^2)$ satisfying

$$\displaystyle D(\vec x) \leq  \lVert \vec x \rVert_2^{- \theta + \varepsilon}.$$

We then say that $\theta = \theta(C)$ is *soft* if for any $c > 0$ there exist infinitely many $\vec x \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus (C \cap \mathbb{Z}^2)$ such that

$$\displaystyle D(\vec x) \leq c \lVert \vec x \rVert_2^{-\theta},$$

otherwise we say that $\theta$ is *hard*.

An example of a curve with a hard boundary exponent is $C : x_1 x_2 = 1$. For all $\vec x = (x, x + 1) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ with $x \geq 1$ we have $D(\vec x) = \frac{1}{x}$, so $\theta(C) = 1$. Further, for any $c < 1$ there are only finitely many $\vec x \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus (C \cap \mathbb{Z}^2)$ satisfying

$$\displaystyle D(\vec x) \leq c \lVert \vec x \rVert_2^{-1}.$$

Conjecturally, the curve $C : y^2 = x^3$ has soft boundary. The weak Hall's conjecture asserts that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $c(\varepsilon) > 0$ such that for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus (C \cap \mathbb{Z}^2)$ we have

$$\displaystyle |y^2 - x^3| \geq c(\varepsilon) x^{1/2 - \varepsilon}.$$

Further, as seen from my earlier question "[Upper bound for Hall's conjecture on separation of squares and cubes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448360/upper-bound-for-halls-conjecture-on-separation-of-squares-and-cubes)", one has that there are infinitely many $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus (C \cap \mathbb{Z}^2)$ such that

$$\displaystyle |y^2 - x^3| < x^{1/2}.$$

To estimate $D(\vec x)$, one notes that

$$\displaystyle |y^2 - x^3| = |y - x^{3/2}||y + x^{3/2}|.$$

Thus the above two inequalities imply that

$$\displaystyle D(x,y) \gg x^{-1 - \varepsilon} \gg |y|^{-2/3 - \varepsilon} = \lVert (x,y) \rVert_2^{-2/3 - \varepsilon}$$

and

$$\displaystyle D(x,y) < \lVert (x,y) \rVert_2^{-2/3}.$$

The original strong Hall's conjecture is now expected to be false, which shows that $C$ conjecturally has a soft boundary.

Note that in the first example, a hard boundary is explained by a rational curve: all of the nearest integer points lie on the line $y = 0$ for $x \geq 1$. This leads to the question:

If $C \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is an algebraic curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ with a hard boundary exponent $\theta$, then do there exist finitely many rational curves $C_k, k \leq N$ such that outside of a compact set, whenever $\vec x \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus (C \cap \mathbb{Z}^2)$ is such that

$$\displaystyle D(\vec x) \ll \lVert \vec x \rVert_2^{-\theta},$$

we have $\vec x \in C_k(\mathbb{Z})$ for some $k \leq N$?